# Datatable ColVis show/hide misplaces data

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am having a very rare problem with my datatable colvis plugin. When I hide and then show the datatable column from the show/hide button of datatable, the data in the table body gets misplaced.

**Example:**

The table looks like this normally. where the *head* are the header of the grid, and the *data* are respective data in the grid.

```
| head1 | head2 | head3 | head4 |

| data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 |

| data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 |

| data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 |
```

Now I hide the *head1* column using the show/hide button of colviz

```
| head2 | head3 | head4 |

| data2 | data3 | data4 |

| data2 | data3 | data4 |

| data2 | data3 | data4 |
```

Ok runs fine, now I again make visible the *head1* column form show/hide button of colvis

```
| head1 | head2 | head3 | head4 |

| data2 | data3 | data4 | data1 |

| data2 | data3 | data4 | data1 |

| data2 | data3 | data4 | data1 |
```

The head1 is at correct place but its data misplaces to the right end, and other columns data misplace to left serially.
I have used colvis at many places and done the similar work all runs fine. But the problem is with this specific one.

What extra things I had.

1. I had row grouping also added, I removed it and checked nothing happened, seems not creating issue.
2. I had multiple header rows, which I have completely removed and seems its not the issue too.

These are my data-table settings.

```
//Settings for datatables
            var extensions = {
                "sFilter": "dataTables_filter",
                "sLength": "dataTables_length"
            }
                        // Used when bJQueryUI is false
                        $.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, extensions);
                        // Used when bJQueryUI is true
                        $.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oJUIClasses, extensions);
            odata = $('#grid').dataTable({
                "sDom":'C<"clear">Rlfrtip',
                "iDisplayLength": 50,
                //"scrollX": true,
                "aLengthMenu": [
                    [ 50, 100,150, -1],
                    [ 50, 100,150, "All"]
                ],
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "oLanguage": {
                 "sSearch": " ",
                 "sZeroRecords":"No Records found, try changing the date range",
                 "oPaginate": {
                   "sLast": ">>",
                   "sFirst":"<<",
                   "sNext" : ">",
                   "sPrevious" : "<"
                 }
                },
                "oColVis": {
                    "buttonText": "Header",
                    "aiExclude": [0,1],
                    groups: [
                        {
                            title: "All",
                            columns: [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
                        }]
                },
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                 { "bSortable": false, "aTargets":[0,1] },
                 { "bVisible" : false, "aTargets":[0,1,2] }
                ] 
            });
```

**Extra Notes :** I have 24 columns working in the grid, and the amount of data pulled into is averaged 2000-10000+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While hit and trial, I found this problem solved by using:

```
new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns( odata );
```

This line of code should be written after initialization of the datatable.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still interested, I had the exact same problem and it seems to be caused by "visible" (or "bVisible" in Hungarian notation) parameter being sent as integer (1 or 0). When I cast it to boolean on backend, the problem went away. I hope this helps.